# Mongo db skip, but skip users matching the query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoskin

In my `users` collection, I am querying users who are over 18 years old, with a limit of 32.
I am now working on a pagination feature. Page 1 should return the first 32 who are 18+ years old (with sorting by `last_visit`), page 2 would return the second 32 users part who are 18+ and so on.

Current code I have looks like:

```
db.bind('users').bind({
  search: function (query, fieldsLimit, page, callback) {
    var skip = page ? page * 32 : 0;

    this.find(query, fieldsLimit).skip(skip).limit(32).sort({ last_visit: -1 }).toArray(function (err, users) {
      callback(err, users);
    });
  }
});
```

Problem to fix: The skip here actually only skips any kind of user, so even if I am on page 2, it still queries many of the same users on page 1.

Comment: skip/limit is not recommended, per the mongodb documentation and other resources. https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/

Comment: Thanks. Will make the `_id` of users available on the client side and when going to the next page, I'll get the `_id` of the last user shown on the page and go from there (adding `_id > last_id`).

Comment: You're sorting by `last_visit` though. Use that for your paging and make sure it has an index.

Comment: Right, was wondering why my previous attempt didn't work. Will do the same logics using last_visit.

Comment: Question about indexes, should I add all the fields in the same index, for example index `{ last_visit: 1, date_of_birth: 1, gender: 1}`, or should they be added separately, with mongo being smart enough to make use of them correctly?